# Why is my SCSS file is not being applied in my React after importing?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

**React.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Facebook from "../../../Assets/Images/Facebook.png";
import Linkedin from "../../../Assets/Images/Linkedin.png";
import Twitter from "../../../Assets/Images/Twitter.png";
import Instagram from "../../../Assets/Images/Instagram.png";
import Youtube from "../../../Assets/Images/Youtube.png";
import Apple from "../../../Assets/Images/Apple.png";
import Googleplay from "../../../Assets/Images/Googleplay.png";
import line from "../../../Assets/Images/Line.png";
import style from "./Footer.scss";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.page}>
      <div className={style.footer}>
        <div className={style.part1}>
          <header className={style.text1}>Newsletter Subscription</header>

          <header className={style.text2}>Careers</header>

          <header className={style.text3}>Contact Us</header>

          <header className={style.text4}>Terms and Conditions</header>

          <header className={style.text5}>Help</header>

          <header className={style.text6}>Send Us Feedback</header>
        </div>

        <div className={style.part2}>
          <div className={style.icon1}>
            <img src={Facebook} alt="facebook" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon2}>
            <img src={Linkedin} alt="Linkedin" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon3}>
            <img src={Twitter} alt="Twitter" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon4}>
            <img src={Instagram} alt="Instagram" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon5}>
            <img src={Youtube} alt="Youtube" />
          </div>
          <div className={style.bar}>
            <img src={line} alt="line" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon6}>
            <img src={Apple} alt="Apple" />
          </div>

          <div className={style.icon7}>
            <img src={Googleplay} alt="Googleplay" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={style.part3}>
          <p>© 2020 National Centre for the Performing Arts, Mumbai.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Footer;
```

This is my code, why am i not able to see the styles in my output?

Is there any dependencies to be added?
I tried importing it another project. It worked there but not in the original project. what could be the reason?

**Footer.scss**

I have no idea why this is happening
there is no particular error in my code but in my output, stylesheet is not being applied.

```
.page {
  height: 380px;
  width: 1920px;
  padding-top: 8810px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 380px;
  width: 1920px;
}

.part1 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.text1 {
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  size: 20px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 373px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.text2 {
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 71px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
}

.text3 {
  size: 20px;
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 81px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
}

.text4 {
  size: 20px;
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
}

.text5 {
  size: 20px;
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 71px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
}

.text6 {
  size: 20px;
  color: #858792;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  opacity: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-left: 81px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
}

.part2 {
  top: 167.5px;
  left: 738px;
  bottom: 164px;
}

.bar {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1;
  float: left;
}

.icon1 {
  float: left;
  top: 8986px;
  left: 738px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding-left: 738px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
}

.icon1:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Facebookhover.png");
}

.icon2 {
  top: 8994px;
  left: 807px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 31px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
  float: left;
}

.icon2:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Linkedinhover.png");
}

.icon3 {
  float: left;
  top: 8997px;
  left: 865px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 29px;
  padding-left: 26.5px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
}

.icon3:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Twitterhover.png");
}

.icon4 {
  top: 8994px;
  left: 928px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
}

.icon4:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Instagramhover.png");
}

.icon5 {
  top: 8986px;
  left: 980px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 24.48px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.icon5:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Youtubehover.png");
}

.icon5:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #858792;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.icon6 {
  top: 8993px;
  left: 1086px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
}

.icon6:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Applehover.png");
}

.icon7 {
  top: 8986px;
  left: 1134px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 31.54px;
  padding-bottom: 59px;
  padding-right: 744.47px;
}

.icon7:hover {
  content: url("../../../Assets/Images/Googleplayhover.png");
}

.part3 {
  color: #858792;
  size: 20px;
  font-family: "ubuntu";
  top: 9070px;
  left: 704px;
  width: 614px;
  height: 23px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #858792;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 654px;
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 105px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Ubuntu;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: As you are trying to use css modules, you need to rename file to `Footer.module.scss` and import as `import styles from "./Footer.module.scss";` (better to call it `styles` i.e. plural)